I am runnig splash container using docker custom netwrok driver macvlan
splash not exposing on port 8050.
#!/bin/bash

# Custom network name
NETWORK_NAME="mynetwork"

# Loop to start 50 containers
for i in {1..20}
do
  docker run -d \
    --name splash_$i \
    --network $NETWORK_NAME \
    scrapinghub/splash
done

the command above is i ma using to run multiple containers each container running fine and getting their ip also fine. but its not exposing splash running.
Idea is i want to make multiple containers so web server see each reqeuest comming from different computer/client.

You don't have a docker run -p option to publish the container port(s).

@DavidMaze right now each container have its own ip. i don't want to route through the base system.

you need a loadbalancer or expose pod port
such as
user -> loadbalancer -> pod1
pod2
user -> machine_ip:port1
user -> machine_ip:port2
when you create a pod without -p, then you only got a pod with ip like 172.x.x.x and cannot access via network. you need to open a port link to your machine or loadbalancer

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
